# PowerShell: How to evaluate each attribute in an object?

Tags: object, powershell, csv, attributes

This can be applied to many different scenarios, but specifically I am running:

```
Import-Csv "file.txt" | foreach { $_ }
```

Generically, the output is:

```
Attribute1 : $true
Attribute2 : asdf
Attribute3 : {}
Attribute4 : $true
```

**How could I run a foreach loop that I could use to compare each attribute's name and value?**    For example see which attribute's equal $true but isn't Attribute4.  (I'm open to using something other than *foreach*, that's just all I know.)

I realize that I could do `(Import-Csv "file.txt").Attribute1`, but I that would be very impractical do this for every attribute.

These attributes will be different types of variables (some strings, some booleans, some arrays) but I'll go one question at a time.

**EDIT :**
I don't think it's relevant, but the CSV file came from
`Get-ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy -Identity "Policy" | Export-Csv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soemthing like this?

```
 Import-Csv "file.txt" | foreach-object { 
 $_.psobject.properties | where-object {
 $_.value -eq $true -and $_.name -ne "Attribute4}
```